# Automatic form filling in Acrobat Reader

Tags: xml, forms, pdf, dll, acrobat

Acrobat Reader allows to import form data from xml file, but this file has to be chosen manually from file system. User has to click "Extended" tab and then "Import data" to browse file system.

Is it possible to load form data automatically without user interaction? I'm looking for an API or DLL, which provides mentioned feature. 
Or maybe there is a way to do it with help of command line and some options?

Answer (score 0):

Are we talking Acroforms or XFA here?

In case of Acroforms, FDF and XFDF have a key specifying the Base PDF. Send the user the (X)FDF, and upon opening, the Base PDF will be loaded (if the path to it is valid).

Another approach would be server-side filling, for which there are several tools out there, such as FDFMerge by Appligent, or libraries such as iText.

Comment: How to check what kind of forms is used? PDF document, which I'm trying to fill, it's not made by me but goverment department.

Comment: Check the document properties; if the Creator says something like "LiveCycle Designer", it is XFA. Another way to find out is fill some fields and export the data; if you do not get reasonable results when exporting as FDF, you have XFA, otherwise, you have a PDF form.

Comment: I checked properties and found this: "PDF Producer: Adobe LiveCycle Forms ES3". I guess we are talking about XFA then.

You showed me, how to do the trick with Acroforms. Is there any way in case of XFA?

Comment: Yes, the form is XFA. I am not sufficiently familiar with XFA (Adobe never cared for a Mac version…). What you can do in any case, is take the form, fill it (partially is sufficient), export the XML file and find the reference to the base PDF document. Then see if opening the XML in Acrobat/Reader will pull up the base form.

Comment: Another place to get to the experts would be the Livecycle section in the Adobe user community.

Comment: XML doesn't have any references to the base PDF document. Should I set something manually? If I just try to open XML in Reader, it says that XML isn't supported format. I asked question in Forms section, but nobody helped me. Maybe I should follow your advice and try in Livecycle section. Thanks for time you spent here.